# Laravel Password Hashing

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords, laravel-5.4

I have a external service which wishes to create user via a bespoke API that I have created in my Laravel application.

Rather than the remote end sending me the password in plain text I would like the remote end to hash the password first however I am unsure on how of the hashing using.

The remote end is using ASP.NET to make things slightly more complicated.

I am guessing Laravel is using CRYPT_BLOWFISH as that is the strongest available on the server but unsure how the salt works. Could anyone advise?

Comment: why do you need to know how the salt works?

Comment: So that the remote end can replicate in their application using ASP.net

Comment: If the client hashes the password and that is obtained by an attacker it becomes the password. Obligatory: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: "bespoke API"? Also is the word "Hasing" in the title also bespoke? (now de-bespoked).

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string. The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithmeter and must be in range 04-31, values outside this range will cause crypt() to fail. Versions of PHP before 5.3.7 only support "$2a$" as the salt prefix: PHP 5.3.7 introduced the new prefixes to fix a security weakness in the Blowfish implementation. Please refer to » this document for full details of the security fix, but to summarise, developers targeting only PHP 5.3.7 and later should use "$2y$" in preference to "$2a$".

Example hash from Laravel:

```
$2y$10$RXyfF5/5qdBeGbwKgU5NR.p1OcgT5t3N.M5ql5PHm.UoxYGOogDWi
```

- 2y = blowfish prefix
- 10 = cost parameter
- RXyfF5/5qdBeGbwKgU5NR. = 22 char salt
- p1OcgT5t3N.M5ql5PHm.UoxYGOogDWi = bcrypt hash